# Kusto - Extract string field into new columns using parse operator

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, re2

I have got a column in my kusto table which contains some log messages of the following form

msg1

`2020-10-29T12:57:08+00:00 dc1-k30-asw05.nw.domain.com cron: :- addNeighbor: Created neighbor ac:1f:6b:8b:09:99 on Vlan100`

msg2

`2020-10-29T15:55:20+00:00 dc1-k12-asw30.domain.com cron: :- validatePortSpeed: Unable to validate speed for port 100000000005c. Not supported by platform`

Now I want to extract some sub strings from it into separate columns, the sub strings I am interested in are the timestamp value (`2020-11-02T10:31:21+00:00`) this is basically the start of the line, the `program`which  emitted the log which is `cron` in this case and lastly the actual log message. So I am using the `parse` operator to do that instead of using multiple `extract` and evaluating the pattern multiple times.

`parse kind = regex message with  @".*?" syslogTime:string @"\s+.*domain.com .*?" program:string  @":  " msg`

This query results in following outputs

```
"syslogTime": 2020-10-29T12:57:08+00:00,
"program":   cron: :- addNeighbor,
"msg": Created neighbor ac:1f:6b:8b:09:99 on Vlan100,
```

```
"syslogTime": 2020-10-29T15:55:20+00:00,
"program":  cron: :- validatePortSpeed,
"msg": Unable to validate speed for port 100000000005c. Not supported by platform,
```

As seen above the first field is parsed correctly however for the second column `program` the value matched in incorrect, the regex engine is doing a greedy match till the second `:` even though I have used a non-greedy quantifier `@"\s+.*domain.com .*?"`.

I have also tried using the ungreedy flag `U` as to the parse query but with that the last part of the message is not being captured.

`parse kind = regex flags=U message with  @".*" syslogTime:string @"\s+.*domain.com.*" program:string  @": " msg`

The output I get

```
"syslogTime": 2020-11-02T08:47:35+00:00,
"program":  cron,
"msg":
```

```
"syslogTime": 2020-10-29T15:53:36+00:00,
"program":  cron,
"msg":
```

For the second column i.e. `program` I want to match till the first ":". I have tried multiple variations of the above queries but none of them yielded the expected output. So I am not sure what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by modifying the parse expression to following.

```
parse kind = regex flags=U message with  @".*" syslogTime:string @"\s+.*domain.com.*" program:string  @": " msg @"$"
```